# Setting series name in Excel Graph causes flicker

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating an Excel Spreadsheet graph using VBA like so:-

```
Private Sub Chart_Calculate()

    Title$ = Range("charttitle")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select

    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory)
        .MinimumScale = 0
        .MaximumScale = 300
        .MinorUnit = 10
        .MajorUnit = 50
        .Crosses = xlCustom
        .CrossesAt = 0
        .ReversePlotOrder = True
        .ScaleType = xlLinear
        .DisplayUnit = xlNone
    End With

End Sub
```

I then attempt to set the series name, like this:-

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = CStr(some_value) & " Some Text"
```

When I add this line of code to the sub, it causes the Chart_Calculate function to be activated numerous times in rapid succession, causing the graph to flicker for a few seconds before stabilising.

Does anyone know what the matter is, and what I should do about it?

(This is Excel 2003 running on Windows XP.)

EDIT: PortlandRunner's suggestion cleared up the problem during the graph redrawing, but it still exists if the Graph is visible at startup. See also [this](http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/p/29632/345353.aspx).

Comment: Not sure why but you can turn off screenupdating=false at the top of your code to prevent the flicker.

Comment: @PortlandRunner, that does fix the flickering problem; thank you. Judging by the time it takes the multiple invokation is still taking place.

Comment: or `Application.EnableEvents = False` while editing the chart to prevent events from firing up

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of your code, and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at/near the end of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; as with Portland Runner's tip, this corrects the problem during calculation, but if one starts up the spreadsheet with the graph page exposed, the flickering still takes place.